# Default keyboard in iOS disappears when bluetooth scanner is connected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard, barcode-scanner

I went through all the links to help show the default keyboard when bluetooth scanner is connected to iPhone. However none of those methods work out for me. I am using Xcode 8.2.1. I need to connect the scanner as well as need the default keyboard at the same time. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, one solution that worked for me was to double tap the button on the scanner, that will bring the default keyboard up. Whenever you use the scanner the default keyboard will be hidden, so you will have to double tap the button each time.

Comment: Is there any other method to achieve this?

Comment: No, which scanner are you using, i had tested it on honeywell scanner

Comment: model number of the scanner